# Cremar rule-geometric interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been reading the information about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Geometric_interpretation) 
all was clear until this sentence:

"Now, this last parallelogram, by Cavalieri's principle, has the same area as the parallelogram determined by $\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}=x_1 \pmatrix{a_{11}\\a_{21}}+x_2 \pmatrix{a_{12}\\a_{22}}$ and $\pmatrix{a_{12}\\a_{22}}$ "

Why is it true?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Cavalieri's principle to understand that. It is just saying that the shaded regions of the middle picture and the bottom picture have the same area.

In the bottom picture, $(b_1,b_2)$ is the summation of the two vectors $x_1\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\end{pmatrix}$ and $x_2\begin{pmatrix}a_{12}\\a_{22}\end{pmatrix}$, hence is the diagonal vector.

The two shaded regions are both parallelogram. The area of a parallelogram is $base\times height$. You can easily observe that the base and the height of the two parallelograms are the same.